# Magento: Limit text field size in product custom attribute to 80 characters

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have a problem by using the following tip from the magento forum:

> **Quote**: 
>   One option you could do is to add a backend model for this attribute.
>   In this model you could write your own `beforeSave` function that will
>   process the length of given value and trim it to be the desired
>   length. The class should extend  `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract`
>
> Code:

```
public function beforeSave($object) {
     $attrCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
     if ($object->hasData($attrCode)) {
         $object->setData($attrCode, substr($object->getData($attrCode),0,50));
     }
     return $this; }
```

**My question now is: how and where do I implement this snippet?** 
I recently put it in `/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Backend/Default.php` but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

first at all, you'll never should place custom code into core files. This destroys your upgradabillity. Create your own custom modules under app/code/local. There you can create your model which extends from Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract.

May this link helps you to create your module:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/

Also you can use magerun (an cli tool for magento) to create a module: http://magerun.net/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried out the smashingmagazine tutorial, but stuck at the `config.xml` where the event is observed. Couldn't find out what to put in there for my purpose. Because I'm a very beginner in magento coding, maybe you can help me to get this working?! Thanks